# On Update command is not working for dynamically created button in MFC

Tags: mfc, cbutton

In my code, i have added button in view class in OnCreate().  I included On Command  and On Update COmmand funtionality. Here On command fucntion is working when i click the button. But On Update COmmand is not working. Im updating the pressing status of the button using this OnUpdateCommand().

In OnCreate()

```
rBar.left = 580;
    rBar.right = 620;
    cBZoomOut.Create("",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_BITMAP ,rBar,this,IDC_TZOOMOUT);
    cBZoomOut.SetIcon(IDI_TZOOMOUT);

    rBar.left = 625;
    rBar.right = 665;
    cBZoomin.Create("",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_BITMAP ,rBar,this,IDC_TZOOMIN);
    cBZoomin.SetIcon(IDI_TZOOMIN);
```

Message maps for those buttons.

```
    afx_msg void OnUpdateTzoomout(CCmdUI *pCmdUI);
    afx_msg void OnTzoomin();
    afx_msg void OnUpdateTzoomin(CCmdUI *pCmdUI);
    afx_msg void OnTzoomout();

    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(IDC_TZOOMOUT, &CTrendView::OnUpdateTzoomout)
    ON_COMMAND(IDC_TZOOMIN, &CTrendView::OnTzoomin)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(IDC_TZOOMIN, &CTrendView::OnUpdateTzoomin)
    ON_COMMAND(IDC_TZOOMOUT, &CTrendView::OnTzoomout)
```

On command and OnUpdatecommand function:

```
void CTrendView::OnTzoomout()
{   
    sTimeStatus.Format("<=>%d",Minute/2);

}
void CTrendView::OnUpdateTzoomout(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{   
    if (Minute == 16)
        pCmdUI->Enable(FALSE);
    else
        pCmdUI->Enable(TRUE);
}
```

In both Zoomin and Zoomout function, OnUpdateCommnad is not working.

Comment: I loaded this inside View. I have added some controls at the end of the View not in childframe.

Comment: Is `cBZoomIn` a `CButton`? In that case you have to enable/disable it manually.

Comment: Yes, it is CButton created dynamically in OnCreate().  decalred in headerfile as CButtonST  cBZoomin,cBZoomOut,;

Comment: You can create a time in your `CView` class and call `cBZoomIn->EnableWindow(TRUE/FALSE)`, or override `CWinApp::OnIdle()`

Answer (score 2):

This routing isn't done automatically.

You have to handle `WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI`. Usually you call the internal `OnUpdateCmdUI` virtual function. This finally calls `UpdateDialogControls`.

You find the details in [TN021](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn021-command-and-message-routing?view=vs-2017)

Just set a breakpoint on a working OnUpdate Handler. And look into the call stack. Than you can see and imagine how the whole stuff works.

There is also a possible way to use `WM_KICKIDLE` and `UpdateDialogControls`. See this [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/wmkickidle-for-updating-mfc-dialog-contr/184416462).

Comment: `WM_IDLEUPDATECOMDUI` is not Windows or MFC message. The `OnUpdateCmdUI` routine may get called only when the associated menu item or tool button needs activation.

Comment: Please read TN024. Is is a MFC message! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn024-mfc-defined-messages-and-resources?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

In `TrendView.h` add this:

```
afx_msg LRESULT OnKickIdle(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

In `TrendView.cpp` add this:

```
#include <afxpriv.h>

...
ON_MESSAGE(WM_KICKIDLE, OnKickIdle)
...

LRESULT CTrendView::OnKickIdle(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UpdateDialogControls(this, FALSE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have included this in both cpp and .h file. But no change. i though by including this, OnUpdateCommandUI will get triggered. Whether it will work only on CDialog class. Because my class is CView.I added controls through coding.